# Has there been no global warming for 18 years?

Tags: climate-change

I have heard Ted Cruz and other people multiple times say that there has been no global warming for the past 18 years.

They usually pull this chart (which has gone viral, and can be found on dozens of web-sites) that apparently shows that satellite data shows no warming for 18 years and 8 months.

Is this claim true?

[image]